How to interpret the EDA data measured by this Pixel Watch 2
I have obtained the EDA data measured by the sensor on Pixel Watch 2, and its format is as follows. How can I get the value of EDA from here?
[-141321.17, 24345.795, 170964.33, 307552.9, 131182.25, -34297.35, -180827.66, -317462.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[-140516.86, 25190.086, 171732.4, 308232.47, 132064.77, -33044.457, -179888.28, -316552.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[-140858.7, 24641.303, 171321.16, 307789.06, 132014.02, -33383.87, -179859.44, -316660.97, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[-139291.27, 25833.979, 172142.55, 308257.2, 132151.86, -32675.396, -179105.16, -315613.47, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[-139062.9, 25764.658, 171824.56, 307705.47, 132231.6, -32483.99, -178611.08, -314983.53, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

I suspect that these are the real and imaginary parts of impedance. The AFE4500 used by the Pixel Watch 2 to measure EDA seems to have four EDA sensors. I believe that these four sensors provide eight values corresponding to the real and imaginary parts of impedance. I would like to hear your thoughts on this.

Where is the data format specification?
